# Scrap Facebook Liker Post

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping

I am currently testing scraping data of Facebook post likes. What I need to know is who has liked this post and the names of the accounts that have liked it. For example, this post: https://www.facebook.com/ProgrammersCreateLife/posts/pfbid0t3yXWp9hrbebb33k8vtDfbLyCWPZVavQFYGrnifjQSx14F2oJfckZfRAED3aaQq3l

Initially, I found that I can retrieve the names of the accounts that have liked a post through this API: https://www.facebook.com/api/graphql/. However, it can only retrieve 10 account names at a time. Additionally, I am not aware of the parameters needed to navigate from the first set of 10 account names to the next set of 10 (i.e., from the list of 1-10 to 11-20)

this is example cURL for get the data

```
curl -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Microsoft Edge";v="114"' -H 'dnt: 1' -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.67' -H 'x-fb-friendly-name: CometUFIReactionsDialogTabContentRefetchQuery' -H 'x-fb-lsd: iM8RJVp9pNRUAHslIa1CCs' -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform-version: "10.0.0"' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'x-asbd-id: 129477' -H 'sec-ch-ua-full-version-list: "Not.A/Brand";v="8.0.0.0", "Chromium";v="114.0.5735.201", "Microsoft Edge";v="114.0.1823.67"' -H 'sec-ch-prefers-color-scheme: light' -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'origin: https://www.facebook.com' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' -H 'referer: https://www.facebook.com/oadenn/posts/pfbid0S47PhLtL24vssrch5kvUWCXfUvYrLKSwNwZvLh9bgSLCMbZxY767Jdb4Y5rWRKz9l' --compressed -H 'accept-language: th' -H 'cookie: sb=Gu-kZPInsXVxuKgiXEFpx4wh' -H 'cookie: wd=1920x937' -H 'cookie: datr=Gu-kZPMvXofvEwqMjjsa4IQ_' -H 'cookie: c_user=100094498830373' -H 'cookie: xs=5%3AzIBhuIsU2I7Ujg%3A2%3A1688530735%3A-1%3A-1' -H 'cookie: fr=06SNNQQIVcklV3sV4.AWXyxJJ6YUGOH53O5jdpG4I2Sjk.BkpO8a.LM.AAA.0.0.BkpO8x.AWUPcKvjHOI' -H 'cookie: presence=C%7B%22t3%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22utc3%22%3A1688531704421%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D' -X POST https://www.facebook.com/api/graphql/ -d 'av=100094498830373&__user=100094498830373&__a=1&__req=1s&__hs=19543.HYP%3Acomet_pkg.2.1..2.1&dpr=1&__ccg=EXCELLENT&__rev=1007788601&__s=m7gwb1%3A9kmokk%3Apnhen6&__hsi=7252188414086170626&__dyn=7AzHJ16UW5Eb8ng5K8G6EjBWobVo66u2i5U4e2C17xt3odEnz8K361twYwJyE24wJwpUe8hwaG0Z82_CxS320om78bbwto88422y11xmfz83WwgEcEhwGxu782lwv89kbxS2218wc61axe3S7Udo5qfK0zEkxe2GewyDwkUtxGm2SUbElxm3y3aexfxmu3W3y261eBx_y88E6a1TxWm2Sq2-azo7u3C223908O3216xi4UdUcojxK2B0oobo8oC1hxB0qo&__csr=g8Ih3sRnltnNR9JsBiH4nsJZFnlHOlOkD-N599T9FtnazkXnFkGlp4AuQJ4bOF96GJ3aGCWJoCl4iZtuhaWhbHF5lczAllyF8GmUKcyWHyvzFVbCmF9K8iDQla9yrh9FWzF8zU-cUKp6gB4zd6ADyoydWUOla8KE4-awg8cEG9zWzoPyF4mq4FV41iyBVWh88orx7xGqqmq5U88cGxh3FUpLyU5q15xq4UG2GfG32UjxG3e1Eyo7i7onxyU4q2S3q4bw_zoaUScwKwDgcU5vw09vt00ub80fj83ww3rU7G0si3y3K10wgEB0Cw6mwbu3y0Kk0eXw2m81XZw0P5Cw3wHhQ0Bo0xC0f480bTD8580hFw1VR01kDzV61jwQw9m1Pg1Ho1yRGl4wBga8CqV-1sw7pw8qu0Eo1qo0PAM7Hw-w&__comet_req=15&fb_dtsg=NAcMQ9XErMzVaux-KujMTTFokT9rht47BqoK9eu5AuNyRprE8Y1pMtw%3A5%3A1688530735&jazoest=25569&lsd=iM8RJVp9pNRUAHslIa1CCs&__spin_r=1007788601&__spin_b=trunk&__spin_t=1688531696&fb_api_caller_class=RelayModern&fb_api_req_friendly_name=CometUFIReactionsDialogTabContentRefetchQuery&variables=%7B%22count%22%3A10%2C%22cursor%22%3A%22AQHR9g7h1HmpVAa6VQbE8Omzaak4FR8hAXpxlXT1XQJ8rvrUi1ttoTRuRkPpC7SNSirAD9jc72VNtHYD9JShBXv5Ug%22%2C%22feedbackTargetID%22%3A%22ZmVlZGJhY2s6ODE5NzIwNjU5NTAzOTY1%22%2C%22reactionID%22%3Anull%2C%22scale%22%3A1%2C%22id%22%3A%22ZmVlZGJhY2s6ODE5NzIwNjU5NTAzOTY1%22%7D&server_timestamps=true&doc_id=5772264139493719'
```

Comment: Just a friendly piece of advice, **never share cookies**.

Comment: what is the use case for this, if i may ask? and why not just use the graph api? facebook does not allow scraping.

Comment: That is not an official API endpoint; you are using something that is only intended for "internal" use here - so don't expect to find any documentation for parameters or anything like that; at most you might be able to "reverse engineer" it. (And then it will still probably just break again, when Facebook decides to change anything about it.)

Comment: I know that officially, Facebook does not provide this service. However, I'm wondering if there is an unofficial way to scrape this data.